# Issue with ~/.profile after fixing NPM permissions

Tags: node.js, macos, permissions, .profile

Installed Node.js on OS X. Fixed the permissions (i.e. sudo required) issue by changing NPM's default directory (https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions see Option 2). However, after booting up commands like `grunt` are not available until I run `source ~/.profile`.

Any way to avoid this hassle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did the node/NPM setup create a ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login file? if so, bash will source that instead of ~/.profile at startup. If this is the problem, there are a couple of ways to fix it:

- Copy the contents of your ~/.profile file into ~/.bash_profile (or ~/.bash_login). You may also want to delete ~/.profile to avoid future confusion.
- Add a command to ~/.bash_profile (or ~/.bash_login) to source ~/.profile as well:

  ```
  [ -f ~/.profile ] && source ~/.profile
  ```

Comment: Migrating export from `~/.profile` to `~/.bash_profile` resolved the issue.